Regex for finding all further occurrences of an expression after a first occurance of this expression
I have a line of text where I want to remove duplicates (that may not have to be directly after another).
For example I´d like to remove 'First' in these lines:
First  Second  Third  First  Fourth  First  Fifth  ->   First  Second  Third  Fourth  Fifth
First  Second  Third  First  First  Fourth  Fifth  ->   First  Second  Third  Fourth  Fifth

How could I achieve this?

Which language/tools/libs/environment do you use? Looks a better fit to other things but regex

javascript/typescript windows vscode

Use split() to convert to an array, remove duplicates from the array, then convert it back to a string with join().

You can use an anonymous callback which can count the replacements, keep the first, and remove the rest. You also seem to assume that surrounding whitespace gets automatically taken care of? What result do you expect from "Remove non-first b's from cyb   dbm     pbr bring t"?

It seems your expected output has removed also some spaces, not only "First". Why in the expected result there are only two spaces after Third?

If you're using JavaScript, try this regex:
\s*\b(\S+)\b(?<=\b\1\b.*\1)



const tests = [
  'First  Second  Third  First  Fourth  First  Fifth',
  'First  Second  Third  First  First  Fourth  Fifth',
  'First  Second  Third  First  Second  First  Fourth  Fifth'
];

const output = tests.map(test => /\s*\b(\S+)\b(?<=\b\1\b.*\1)/g[Symbol.replace](test, ''));

console.log(output);




If they are properly in the form of ascending order (if there are no duplicates), then maybe the regex you could 'get away with' would be something like:
(First)?\s+(Second)?\s+(Third)?\s+(Fourth)\s+(Fifth)

This would capture things like:
First Second Third Fourth Fifth
First Second Third
Second Third
First Fifth


I assumed the words are just examples, not literal. They just want to remove all duplicates of whatever the first word is.

Even if it is literal, I don't see how this will remove all the duplicate First words from either of the two examples they gave. I don't think you understood the question.
